# When should I use Docker (locally) when running my development app?

Tags: docker, backend

Sorry if this question is too opinion-based.. But I have been learning Docker and wondering whether I should use Docker on my local machine instead of the good ol'way for every run of my app *or* use it just to test if it works correctly before deploying? Because Docker looks too scary and complex to me.

I'm somewhat not concerned about speed of build time because if caching is used correctly, it is almost instantaneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running app in Docker while development is good practice, because:

- You will run your app in the same environment as in production, so some errors can be revealed much earlier
- Sometimes you will need to edit your `Dockerfile` or `docker run` options. For example, mount new folder. If you constantly run your app in Docker, you will not postpone such manipulations.
- Usually, container OS and your working OS are different, so if you need system-dependent features, running in Docker is only way to see how they will work.

Comment: Thank you a lot, now i discovered that there exists -v option, i am now using it a lot easier (with cmd /bin/sh in run command), just like i would do in my normal desktop